# Child process when to kill

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

When my node project is started it create a child process , this needed to be done just once so I put this code on the server.js file, 
In the child process I execute command like npm install... 
my questions is :

1. Do I need to kill sometime this process?
2. What could happen if the node application is down before I able to
   kill it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Do I need to kill sometime this process?

Ans: If that process is not going to get used further then you better kill it once its job is done.

2.What could happen if the node application is down before I able to kill it?

Ans: If your main node application goes down then your child processes are ultimately gonna get killed so you don't need to worry about it.